# Make a div a link in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Everything I've searched for has shown about making a full div clickable, what I'm wondering is, is it possible to make a div in to a clickable link using just JavaScript and the div ID?

I have a layout of boxes and if a value in my database, I want PHP to echo some values in to JavaScript and say if this box is taken, give this div (boxID) the link that relates to it from the database. Only, there aren't going to be links on every div, as some won't exist in the database.

I suppose the alternative to this is wrapping each div in a `<a>` tag and an if exists statement?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: jquery: `$("div#clickable").click(function(){ window.location = "http://whatever.com/"});` works for you? However, you probably want to do something else. Please tell us more about your problem and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Abuse divs, it sounds like.  Any reason not to make it a real link or a button?

Comment: `window.location = url`

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. There are of course legitimate reasons to make divs clickable but very few to make divs into links. Please edit your question to give more information on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That'd be a **bad answer** IMO. Hence, a comment telling that it's a bad answer and that we need more data for the good answer...

Comment: @BN83, is this a specific problem in your code? If so, please post your code, the expected results, and the actual results to get better help.

Comment: Have updated my post, hopefully giving a bit more info for my issue/query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can easily make it so that when you click your div you go to another page, like this (using jQuery)

```
$('#myId').click(function () {
    window.location = 'newurl.php';
});
```

Comment: I want the `<div>` link to have a right click pop-up menu and open the link to the new tab. That solution doesn't have that feature.

Answer (score 9):

In pure JS:

```
document.getElementById('your-div').addEventListener('click', function() {
    location.href = 'http://your-url.com'
}, false);
```

By jQuery

```
$('#your-div').on('click', function() {
    location.href = 'http://your-url.com'    
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In html5 you can just do:

```
<a href="link"><div>test</div></a>
```

Comment: I'm about 42% certain that a block element inside a link is invalid HTML.

Comment: @cHao I'm to 100% sure that in html(5) an anchor is a _transparent_ element, that could either be a _flow element_ or a _phrasing element_ . And the best thing even that that specs are _new_ all browsers already treated the anchor tag that way.

Comment: You can go either way for HTML5, it's invalid for HTML4 and lower.

Comment: simple example to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/94ymQ/1/ the entire div is clickable inside the `a` tag

Comment: Had to edit it so I can remove my downvote (I thought it was not valid html) and added the `In html5`, upvoted for being correct and teaching me something new (;

Comment: +1 here too; with the "in HTML5" added, this is probably the best answer.  Certainly the easiest to read.  :)

Answer (score 2):

This solution is for html <= 4. For html5, please read @Spencer solution.

Since the javascript is probably not what you want (waiting for extra comments), here's a example of how to do this in pure html/css. An anchor tag that fills completely a div, *making* that div clickable.

html:

```
<div>
  <a href = "http://whatever.com/">
  </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Demo in jsfiddle (background-color added for demonstration purposes):

> http://jsfiddle.net/Gx3f5/

Comment: +1 for not telling people how to do the wrong thing.  :)  Although if you're going to go through this trouble, you might as well just get rid of the div.  Once the link is a block exactly as big as the div, the div doesn't have much purpose anymore.

Comment: I'm assuming he's already doing something else with that div, not only holding the `<a>`, however I didn't feel it was needed to fill the div with more data. [this is what I expected it to be in a real life situation](http://jsfiddle.net/Gx3f5/1/).